# focus is not happening for the error filed in IE using parsley js validator. This works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus, parsley, focusout

For required filed on focus out triggers parleys validator and also iam listening for **'field:validated'** parsley event.Inside this event handler i am getting **back the focus** to this error element.This is working fine for chrome ,but in IE focus is goining to next element and shows two error messages as show here in the below pic.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msb5j.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#person').parsley(); // binding parsley to the form
});

window.Parsley.on('field:validated', function(e) {
  // This global callback will be called for any field that fails validation.
   
  if(this.$element.hasClass('parsley-error')){
   
   this.$element.focus();
  }
});
```

```css
.div1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
    height:600px;
}
.par-error ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
 <style type="text/css">
  .div1{
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   width: 600px;
   height:600px;
  }
  .par-error ul{
   list-style: none;
      display: inline;
      color: red;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1" id="div1" data-candy="chaco">
 <form id="person" name="person" data-parsley-validate>
  <legend>
   Person Information
  </legend>
  <label for="firtsname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="firtsname" data-parsley-errors-container="#fname-error" data-parsley-trigger="blur" data-parsley-validate-if-empty="true" data-parsley-required="true"  />
  <span class="par-error" id="fname-error"></span>
  <br>
  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
  <input data-parsley-focus="none" type="text" id="lastname" data-parsley-errors-container="#lname-error" data-parsley-trigger="blur" data-parsley-validate-if-empty="true" data-parsley-required="true" />
  <span class="par-error" id="lname-error"></span>
  <br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email"/><br>
  <label for="dob">DOB</label>
  <input type="text" id="dob"/><br>
  <input type="submit"></input>
 </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.3.11/parsley.js">
</html>
```

pls need solution for this. Here is the jsbin link[enter link description here](https://jsbin.com/viracu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: What is the exactly error...

Comment: when i tab from input element without entering anything focus should get back to the element back since its a required field.but in ie focus is not working.u can try(chome and ie)it in this link https://jsbin.com/viracu/1/edit?html,css,js,output in chrome this working fine.